# Запятая перед как

Tags: как, пунктуация

Добрый день. Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая перед союзом как в этих предложениях:

> 1. Он представляет себе ее(,) как идеальную женщину.
> 2. Он понимает искусство(,) как способ бегства.

Мне кажется, что в обоих случаях запятая не нужна, но я не могу найти обоснования.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В приведенных примерах обороты с союзом КАК имеют значение "в качестве" и не обособляются.

В первом предложении оборот тесно связан со сказуемым, а во втором он является обстоятельством в основном сообщении.